# var_dump and die like php, In ruby on rails (debug in ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

This might be repeated question. But I can't `display the object`.

I'm new to ruby, tried to debug like `var_dump` and `print_r`  then `die` in `php`

Here is my code.

```
@brand_id = Brand.maximum("brand_id")
```

I tried the following method

```
1 puts YAML::dump(@brand_id)
2 logger.debug { @brand_id.inspect }
```

Can anyone help me resolve it, pls?

Comment: where do you want to display it?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: You can do `abort YAML::dump(@brand_id)` which will stop the execution and output in an error page.

Comment: For me `puts variable.inspect` worked well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rails will only output views to the browser. Any other output is sent to STD_OUT on the server.

Debugging from views is simple:

```
<%= debug @brand %>
```

But debugging from inside a controller or model requires you to either halt the execution with abort, which will output an error page:

```
abort @brand.inspect
```

Or you can write to the rails log with:

```
logger.debug(@brand.inspect)
```

You can read the log by using `tail -f /logs/development.log` from the your shell.

Comment: But there are much better debugging tools like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) that let you set breakpoints instead.

Answer (score 3):

The Rails equivalent of php's `var_dump` would be [`debug`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html#method-i-debug):

```
<%= debug @brand_id %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To display it in the browser you need to add the following code in the view of the action where you are setting the value of `@brand_id`

```
<%= @brand_id %>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: In controller action you need to set `@brand_id`, `@brand_id = Brand.maximum("brand_id")`

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but useful. What about this?

```
render plain: @brand
```